# Designer button grayed out in macro-enabled presentation in PowerPoint. How to fix it?

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I don't know if it's a bug or a “feature”, but if you're creating a macro-enabled presentation in PowerPoint the designer button is grayed-out.

As usual the [Microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/troubleshoot-designer-in-powerpoint-83789fcb-f1ae-4703-b1b4-9c97259f592b) is very “useful”. This is what they have to say about this issue:

> If you can see the **Designer** button in PowerPoint but it's grayed out, it means:
>
> **You aren't connected to the internet**, or
>
> **A single slide isn't selected**. This can be the case when multiple slides are selected in the slide thumbnail pane in Normal view, or when the focus in the thumbnail pane is between two slides. It also can happen when the focus is in the Notes pane or you are in Slide Show view rather than Normal view.

As this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248250/133792) says, we can only embed video in specific StackExchange sites, so, I posted a video of the occurrence on my YouTube channel, [here](https://youtu.be/gC1WPnOOGXg).

[image: An image displaying the grayed-out Designer button on PowerPoint.]

Answer (score 0):

There may be a valid reason for this; perhaps MS doesn't want to interfere with an already-existing design or set of shapes that a macro depends on.

But you can create the slide(s) with Designer and later add the VBA code you need (for example, by copy/pasting it or exporting/importing modules from the existing PPTM to your new presentation, then saving it as a PPTM.)